# How to encapsulate code for WCF services without using a base class?

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, extensibility

All of our services take a ServiceCallContext object as a parameter. The service then creates a broker and tells the broker what connection string to use based on the ServiceCallContext.

In other words, some of our customers have their own databases so the service calls have to point the brokers to their databases.

I would like to take the code that looks at the ServiceCallContext and chooses the correct connection and put it in a base service class. My team lead doesn't like that idea because with services he feels that this would be 'hiding' behavior and that this would be a bad thing. He suggested that there may be better ways to accomplish the same thing through some sort of WCF extensions.

I honestly don't care how we implement the code so long as I can reuse it because I think it's absolutely silly for me to be rewriting it in every service I create. I began looking into some WCF videos on PluralSight and it looks like there's a lot of great stuff it can do but unfortunately I'm not quite sure where to start. Can anyone give me a little direction as to whether WCF can accomplish what I'm trying to do and if so what particular features of WCF am I looking for?

Comment: I think your teamlead has something there with regards to extensions.  WCF is rather nicely designed and allows for custom behaviours; interceptors and so forth.  All this and promotes **code reuse** too.  One needs to be mindful of c# single-class inheritance restriction before creating a base class whos usefulness may limit you.   http://www.amazon.com/Programming-WCF-Services-Mastering-AppFabric-ebook/dp/B0043D2DUK/ref=sr_1_2?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1404102735&sr=1-2&keywords=wcf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functionality you need is a [custom interceptor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751495%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

This allows you to tell the WCF stack to look at incoming messages and the do some action based on them. If you wrap the interceptor up into it's own assembly then you can reference it from multiple services.